# MongoDB data modeling: Document embedding dilemma

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

Say I a have an application which receives requests with two parameters: X and Y. All I want to do is to count these requests, and I want to use MongoDB for the task.

I can think of two methods to store that information in MongoDB:

1.
Having a document for each combination of X and Y:

```
{
  _id : "X+Y",
  count : 34
}
```

2.
Embedding Y into X, meaning that each X has a document which summarizes all of requests with that X:

```
{
  _id : "X",
  total_count : 47,
  y: {
      "Y1" : 34,
      "Y2" : 13
   }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of each of these methods?
Is one method consitered best practice? Is there another legitimate method I'm missing? Is this a common dilemma?

I've been reading MongoDB's manual [data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) section and [a FAQ discussing this issue](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-embed-documents-within-other-documents), but I wasn't satisfied.

Thanks

**Update**

My application is expected to handle about 50M requests a day, while each request holds a few attributes (such as X and Y), but a relatively small amount of them (4-5), and each request should be counted (either by insert or update).
This data will be queried every hour or so, and the queries are expected to use aggregation. These queries will usually query data from the last few days (up to a week).

Answer (score 0):

If you think there might be any chance you would need get a total count grouped by X, then stick with the 2nd method. Furthermore, if there is a chance you might need it grouped by Y, that's not a bad practice to denormalize your data and store Xs embedded in Ys along with Xs embedded in Ys. 
That is because mongo's poor performance with aggregating.

If you are sure you would not need any type of aggregation, 1st method would be better in means of faster read/write and less disk space usage.

Or if you're not completely sure, store it like this: `{x: "X", y: "Y", count: 42}`. Make sure you create index `{x: 1, y: 1}` for that. This way you still keep an option to retrieve all documents by "X" or "Y". Note that having `{x: 1, y: 1}` index means you dont need to create `{x: 1}` index for querying by "X", only `{y: 1}` to query by "Y".

Comment: The 1st method would be better in terms of read/writes?! Maybe if I query a specific X and Y, right? Because if I query multiple types, I must be querying multiple documents (more than in the 2nd method), and as I understand it, the more documents you query the worst it gets, no?

Answer (score 0):

Having abstract documents like this makes it difficult to give advice, but please avoid using non-descriptive keys (or values as keys). Please update your questions with a real-world example of your document, and which queries (insert, update and find) you think you will need to use. Those are the only criteria that can be used to design a proper schema.

Comment: I've updated the question, though I still think these methods can be described with pros and cons regardless of the real-world example.